# html2canvas only renders the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

```js
ticket_list = [0, 1, 2];

function genPDF(){
    var deferreds = [];
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    for (let i = 0; i < ticket_list.length; i++) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferreds.push(deferred.promise());
        genCanvas(i, doc, deferred);
    }

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function () { // executes after adding all images
        doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
}

function genCanvas(i, doc, deferred){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("div"+i), {
        onrendered: function(canvas){
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10, 350, 125, 'center');
            doc.addPage();

            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
}

$('#download').click(function(){
    genPDF();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
     <p>A</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
     <p>B</p>
</div>

<div id="div3"> 
     <p>C</p>
</div>
```

There appears no error when I run this script, but the pdf file is strange.

It loops 3 times but only the same div gets rendered 3 times.

I don't know what should I do.

Anybody help me.

Comment: I can solved problem by edit "doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10, 350, 125, 'center');" to "doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10, 350, 125);" but the order is random. T.T

Answer (score 1):

황준필, From `jdPDF` addImage [Doc](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage)

> addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, compression, rotation)

The seventh parameter of addImage is `alias` which you assign `'center'`, its Description is

> alias of the image (if used multiple times)

So if literal string was given, same `imageData` always be added into `doc`,

Try use a variable like below or just ignore this parameter.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('div' + i), {
    onrendered: function(canvas){
        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10, 350, 125, 'div' + i);
        doc.addPage();

        deferred.resolve();
    }
});
```